# Occurence of not repeated string in alist of list of strings (update with more conditions)

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list of list like this one :

```
List=[['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang], ['Rana', ['Z', 'Y']]
```

****Update: In this list, I had another structure where the first element is a single element and the second element is a list like ['Rana', ['Z', 'Y']], which means that Rana has a specific relationship with Z and R, which are not the same relationship as Rana and Jhon. ****

I want to calculate the occurence of the word of this list and I need two kind of output. The first one when we have a duplicated (or repeated word), we ignore it. The second solution, when we detect the repeated word we count it as once not twice.

**Update: I want to add this type of relation to be included in the second output.**

For example for the first solution the result will be
Rana:2
Jhon:1
Zhang:1

the second solution will be
Rana:3 **(Update: will be 5 instead of 3 since we will consider Z and Y)**
Jhon:1
Zhang: 1

I have tried to develop the following lignes of code, but I didn´t have results:

```
from collections import Counter
List1=[["Rana", "Jhon"], ["Rana", "Rana"], ["Jhon", "Rana"], ["Rana", "Alex"]]
count=0
n=0
for j in range (0, len(List1)-1):
  if (List1[j][0] == List1[j][1] ) or (List1[j][0] != List1[j][1] ):
    count += 1
print(count)
```

Comment: "If they're the same, or they're not the same..." is a strange thing to test.

Comment: Why not `for j in List1`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the first part you can ignore the inner list with repeating values by:

```
Lst=[['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang']]

l = [x for x in Lst if len(set(x))==len(x)]     #len(set()) will make sure only unique elements are there in inner-list
#[['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang']]

#Flatten l by

m = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
#['Jhon', 'Rana', 'Rana', 'Zhang']

from collections import Counter as c
c(m)

#output
Counter({'Jhon': 1, 'Rana': 2, 'Zhang': 1})
```

`len(set(x))` converts `x` into a `set`. If there are repeating values then the `len(x)` will **NOT be equal** to `len(set(x))`

For the second part if there are same values in an inner list you can add only 1 value by:

```
Lst=[['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang']]

l = [x if len(set(x))==len(x) else [x[0]] for x in Lst ]
#[['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang']]

#Flatten l by:

n = [item for sublist in l for item in sublist]
#['Jhon', 'Rana', 'Rana', 'Rana', 'Zhang']

from collections import Counter as c
c(n)

#output
Counter({'Jhon': 1, 'Rana': 3, 'Zhang': 1})
```

---

**Edit:**

Now, if you have a list with reverse elements like:

```
Lst1=[["Rana", "Jhon"], ["Rana", "Rana"], ["Jhon", "Rana"], ["Rana", "Alex"]]
```

You can remove `["Jhon", "Rana"]` and `["Rana", "Rana"]` by:

`#["Rana", "Rana"] is also an inverse of itself.`

```
seen = set()
new_Lst1 = [x for x in Lst1 if tuple(x[::-1]) not in seen and not seen.add(tuple(x))]

print(new_Lst1)
[['Rana', 'Jhon'], ['Rana', 'Alex']]


#Flatten new_Lst1 by

p = [item for sublist in new_Lst1 for item in sublist]
#['Rana', 'Jhon', 'Rana', 'Alex']

from collections import Counter as c
c(p)

#output
Counter({'Rana': 2, 'Jhon': 1, 'Alex': 1})
```

Comment: Hello, I tried the code, but it only check if we have the same string in a list then it takes only one. The case when I have the same list but maybe the position change is not tested. like the example [[Rana, Jhon], [Jhon, Rana]]

Comment: @spainengy If the position is changed, what do you want in output?

Comment: The out put should count it once time not twice. [Rana, Jhon], [Jhon, Rana] ---> Rana 1, Jhon 1

Comment: gotcha.. let me update my answer

Comment: In addition, if it is possible can you explain to me the function you use that extract the  sublists which are not duplicated: l = [x for x in Lst if len(set(x))==len(x)].

Comment: @spainengy did you see the updated answer?

Comment: Yes thank you, I check the code and it works for my list... Now I will try to check other conditions. I hope I will manage thi sby myself, otherwise I  will return back

Answer (score 1):

For what I can understand from your description, using https://stackoverflow.com/a/30357006:

```
from collections import defaultdict

list_1 = [['Jhon', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Rana'], ['Rana', 'Zhang']]
# list_1 = [['Rana', 'Jhon'], ['Jhon', 'Rana']]

seen = []

for sub in list_1:
    sub = sorted(sub)
    if sub not in seen:
        seen.append(sub) 

res_1 = defaultdict(lambda: 0)
res_2 = defaultdict(lambda: 0)

for sub in seen:
    a, b = sub
    if a == b:
        res_2[a] += 1;
    else:
        res_2[a] += 1
        res_2[b] += 1
        res_1[a] += 1;
        res_1[b] += 1;


print(dict(res_1)) #=> {'Jhon': 1, 'Rana': 2, 'Zhang': 1}
print(dict(res_2)) #=> {'Jhon': 1, 'Rana': 3, 'Zhang': 1}
```

Or add more cases, as already commented.

Comment: Thank you, your solution is good an easy to understand, Now I will work with more conditions and if I find problems I will return back with more cases and conditions.